# Change from triple to double bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a csv that looks like this:

[image]

With the following code:

```
data %>%  
    pivot_longer(-country) %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    aes(x = country, y = value, fill = name) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#108CDF", "#0DD016", "#DA560A")) +
    theme_light() + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
    scale_fill_discrete(name = "Metric", 
                        labels = c("1 room in the center", 
                                   "1 room outside the center", 
                                   "Average Monthly Salary")) + 
    xlab("Country") + 
    ylab("USD")
```

I get a triple bar chart with all three variables like so:

[image]

The thing is that I would like to keep the salary bar, but instead of ploting the other two, I would want to plot only one of them that I'm choosing as a shiny input, being able to alternate between them.

I know how inputs work with shiny (input$x48 and input$x49), what I don't know is how to modify the plot as to only show 2 of the variables and not all 3.

Thank you in advance for the help.

---

Data

```r
data <- structure(list(country = c("Andorra", "Austria", "Belgium", "Denmark", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece"), x48 = c(811.73, 710.0385, 765.8359, 961.434, 701.9176, 716.7308, 701.6187, 468.1942), x49 = c(655.2433, 607.8058, 628.3675, 692.426, 575.4287, 587.7711, 544.2052, 370.2103), x54 = c(2801.597, 2224.757, 2320.216, 3130.023, 2582.625, 2399.011, 2621.368, 804.5603)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Please dont post your data as a screenshot, and use something like `dput` instead

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: walter, I suggested an edit to your question that includes usable `data`, please use that or similar methods for sharing data. Thanks! I screen-scraped it and did not verify the values.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiarized with stack, thank you so much for the editing

Answer (score 1):

We could filter the long format of your data first for x48 and second for x49. The only thing you have to replace is x49 by x48 and the label and color by "#0DD016", "1 room outside the center":

I tewaked the code a little:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_long <- df %>%  
  pivot_longer(-country) 

ggplot(data = df_long %>% 
         filter(name %in% c("x48", "x54")),  
                aes(x = country, y = value, fill = factor(name))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#108CDF", "#DA560A")) +
  theme_light()  +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Metric", labels = c("1 room in the center", "Average Monthly Salary")) + 
  labs(fill =" Metric", x= "Country", y= "USD")
```

**First plot: with "x48", "x54":**
[image]

**First plot: with "x49", "x54":**
[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("Andorra", "Austria", "Belgium", "Denmark", 
"Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece"), x48 = c(811.73, 710.0385, 
765.8359, 961.434, 701.9176, 716.7308, 701.6187, 468.1942), x49 = c(655.2433, 
607.8058, 628.3675, 692.426, 575.4287, 587.7711, 544.2052, 370.2103
), x54 = c(2801.597, 2224.757, 2320.216, 3130.023, 2582.625, 
2399.011, 2621.368, 804.5603)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: I'm not being able to execute it, I get the following msj:   `Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") :   no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class "function"`

Comment: Sorry, I had some remnants of prior code... Now it works but the problem is that, in order to see different outputs, I have to change the code. What I need is to instead having to change "x48" to "x49", having the input from shiny (input$var) since it updates automatically. I tried changing the code to `filter(name %in% c(input$x1, "x54"))` but it didn't work.

Comment: This is what I had in mind from the beginning. But with respect this is another question. So I suggest to open a new quesiton with a minimal shiny reproducible example. You will learn most by doing a reproducible example. Without this it is always a guess and not sufficient. :-)

Comment: you are right, I'll do that, thank you!

Comment: I posted the question with a reproducible example if you want to check it out!

Comment: So @akrun already answered your other question?! Good that it worked!